# Which device (in /dev) is the HDMI CEC device?

Tags: cec-client

I want to interact directly with the CEC protocol on my raspberry pi. How can I find out which device to use?

Comment: is it `/dev/cec0`?

Comment: It doesn't exist in `/dev`. I'm using the latest version of Raspbian

Answer (score 1):

I understand the device name is `/dev/vchiq`, but you can't use it directly unless you get relevant VideoCore documentation. `libcec` [uses](https://github.com/Pulse-Eight/libcec/tree/master/src/libcec/adapter/RPi) the VideoCore API, which doesn't mention device names directly. Unless you want to use RPi-specific hardware features (and you know how to do it), you should just use `libcec`.

Answer (score 0):

on my raspbian installation it's /dev/ttyACM0

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no such port on a Pi, unless you connect a USB device to it.

Comment: Isn't it `/dev/cecN`